# Cannot write file with apache despite 777 permissions on Directory

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, permissions

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 and then added a php script that was working fine on Ubuntu 10.04. The script writes a new file to a directory.
The Directory is owned by www-data:www:data and has permissions set to 777.
I have googled and searched SO & SF and tried many different approaches. I have restarted apache, rebooted the server, and I still get the same error:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access /pdfFiles/new_file.pdf
>   on this server.

It is worth noting that pdfFiles is a directory under the webroot for this site. I have created a directory at the root of the system (/pdfFiles/) with the same owner and permissions

the apache error log contains nothing helpful to me:

> (13)Permission denied: access to /pdfFiles/new_filepdf denied,
>   referer:http://mysite/create_file.pdf

I am not running SELinux

Directory:

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Can you post the `<Directory>` section from your Apache config that corresponds to that path?

Comment: edited the original post to include

Comment: Can the php script read from that directory?  Can it write into the system (not webroot) /tmp directory?

Comment: In a webserver setup context, having a 777 directory inside DocumentRoot is a double security risk: first one is a general pitfall regarding permissions, second one theoretically allow uploading executable code into DocumentRoot and execute it with web server privileges - at this point your server is compromised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. show output of mount(8) to see what file attributes you have on that filesystem
2. also try using su to switch to user that apache and use touch $FILE in same directory
3. I know you said you not running SELinux but try "getenforce" just to make sure.

Comment: #2 did the trick - well, at least it revealed the problem. the apache user (www-data) could not create a file in the directory, it could not even cd into it. I deleted the directory, recreated it, I am the owner, I changed the group to www-data and perms to 774 and it all just works now. THANKS!